# SQL Juncture with other table made of 2 keys

Tags: sql-server

So I have a table named `Patient`.

[image]

And another table named `Ordonnance`.

[image: enter]

A Patient has many Ordonnances, while an Ordonnance should be related to only one Patient ( patient : 1.n with Ordonnance : 1.1 )

My problem is that the Patients primary key is composed with 2 keys ( id_pers + catégorie )

But for the Ordonnances foreign key is only one field ( id_pers )

My first thought was adding another field for Ordonnance and name it ( category ) and then make the relation between the 2 tables, 
but it kinda didn't feel right for me.

If anyone has a better idea on how to solve I would be very happy.

Comment: I guess you could just change the PK in `Patient` to `id_pers` and then create a unique index on `Patient` using `id_pers` and `categorie`.

Comment: @JimHewitt smart idea , is there gonna be any later problems with this solution ?

Comment: There should be no other problem with @jim-hewitt's suggestion except if there is actually a need for the primary key to be composed of those two columns.

Comment: @Reda I would never tell you that it won't with absolute certainty, but I am assuming this is something you can test thoroughly.  Also, you probably should put a unique index on `id_pers` in `Ordannance

Comment: @JimHewitt -- just curious, why do you think there should be a unique index on `id_pers` in `Ordonnance`? I think @Reda is stating that there should be many ordonnances per patient. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @Yobik - Good point.  I suggested that only if the change I proposed was made.  Note, there is already a PK on `Ordonnance`.

Comment: The category depends on the person, so it shouldn't be part of it's key (goes against normalization rules). Remove the category from the PK and problem solved. If the same person can have multiple categories, then remove the category outside as another 1 to N table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opportunity, seems like you may want to change the table such that there is single column primary key for both Patient and Ordonnance. These seem to be concepts that can stand alone and shouldn't require a composite key.

Perhaps the relational diagram could look something like this:

```
table Patient (
    PatientId primary key);

table Ordonnance (
    OrdonnanceId primary key,
    PatientId references Patient(PatientId));
```

Based on your requirements, there should **not** be a unique index on Ordonnance(PatientId).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Ordonnances` table must contain composite key `id_pers + catégorie` as per your Partent Table for correct mapping unless you requirements are different.

Or

You need to make changes in both the tables.